# Uncaught TypeError: Untaming of guest constructed objects unsupported: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, I have a form in an HTML page, and it is supposed to submit the form to a function upon submit. However, when the user clicks Submit, this message appears in the Console.

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Untaming of guest constructed objects unsupported: [object Object]
> ```

I'm using [code from Labnol](http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/) for guidance

Here is all the code:

`code.gs`

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<?!= include('bootstrap'); ?>
<?!= include('style'); ?>

     <div class="container"> 
           <div class="row bottom-margin">
                      <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h1> THE FORM </h1>
                       </div>
                       </div>

          <div class="span4">
               <form id="form">
                    <div class="row bottom-margin">
                         <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First name..">
                         </div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="row bottom-margin">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name..">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <p> How would like to receive your order? </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row bottom-margin">
                    <div class="span12">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> Mail ($1 charge)
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> Locker Drop Off
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> Meet at next Event etc.
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row bottom-margin">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myFile">
                    </div>
                    </div>

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload File" 
                           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                           makeAlert($('#form'));
                           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                           .uploadFiles(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                           return false;">
                           Submit
                       </button>
                      </div>
                 </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
function makeAlert(item){
  console.log(item);
}
function fileUploaded(status) {
  document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
</script>


<?!= include('jquery'); ?>
<?!= include('bootstrapjs'); ?>
```

Comment: _Here is all the code._ Not quite... You've used `include()` to pull in files that you don't provide. You don't show `uploadFiles()`. You don't show the gs HtmlService calls that display the form. In short: this isn't a [mcve]. Instead of expecting us to figure out the parts you _didn't_ show, could you put some effort into providing exactly what's needed to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screen Recording]

The error you reported, *Untaming of guest constructed objects unsupported*, is reporting that the object you've passed as a `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` form, is not exactly that. Your attempt at logging the value before it is passed is a good instinct, but since the console ends up simply showing `[object object]`, it's not much help.

It will help to ensure the message printed by `makeAlert()` is readable, by converting any `object`s to strings:

```
function makeAlert(item){
  console.log("makeAlert: "+JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

With that, you'll see something like this on the console:

```
makeAlert: {
  "0": {
    "0": {},
    "1": {},
    "length": 2,
    "elements": {
      "0": {},
      "1": {},
      "myFile": {}
    },
    "target": "",
    "noValidate": false,
    "name": "",
    "method": "get",
    "encoding": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "enctype": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "autocomplete": "on",
    "action": "",
    "acceptCharset": ""
  },
  "length": 1,
  "context": {
    "location": {
      "hash": "",
      "search": "",
      "pathname": "/userCodeAppPanel",
      "port": "",
      "hostname": "n-myhzlyl6lgsiepuppv5btyezx3ibnjwczjyz6ii-script.googleusercontent.com",
      "host": "n-myhzlyl6lgsiepuppv5btyezx3ibnjwczjyz6ii-script.googleusercontent.com",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "origin": "https://n-myhzlyl6lgsiepuppv5btyezx3ibnjwczjyz6ii-script.googleusercontent.com",
      "href": "https://n-myhzlyl6lgsiepuppv5btyezx3ibnjwczjyz6ii-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel",
      "ancestorOrigins": {
        "0": "https://n-myhzlyl6lgsiepuppv5btyezx3ibnjwczjyz6ii-script.googleusercontent.com",
        "1": "https://script.google.com"
      }
    },
    "jQuery19107126029687933624": 1
  },
  "selector": "#form"
}
```

The error that I received with this minimized code was a little different than yours:

> Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0

The illegal value (that doesn't belong in a form) is:

```
    "jQuery19107126029687933624": 1
```

Look at the minimized HTML, and recount the parent elements of your `<button>`, you'll find there are three, not four. Reduce the `.parentNode()` calls by one, and the error clears up.

With that, the file gets transferred to the server side, and is uploaded. There is another error though:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

This is simply because of a typo in your JavaScript, probably from a cut & paste action, as there is no form named `'myForm'`.

Here's the minimized code that I've tested successfully:

#### Index.html

```
<html>
<div class="container">
  <div class="span4">
    <form id="form">


      <div class="row bottom-margin">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myFile">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload File" onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                           makeAlert($('#form'));
                           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                           .uploadFiles(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                           return false;">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function makeAlert(item) {
    console.log("makeAlert: " + JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'none'; // No form "myForm"
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

#### Code.gs

There was no Google Apps Script code provided in the question, so this is a guess at the functionality provided by `doGet()` and `uploadFiles()`.

```
/**
 * Serves HTML of the application for HTTP GET requests.
 *
 * @param {Object} e event parameter that can contain information
 *     about any URL parameters provided.
 */
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


// adapted from code from http://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files
/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {

  /* Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved */
  var dropbox = "Dropbox";
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

  /* Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist */
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
  }

  /* Get the file uploaded through the form as a blob */
  var blob = form.myFile;    
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

  /* Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive */
  return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

}
```

Comment: When I tried `JSON.stringify(item)` I got some kind of error about `circular reference`

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed answer! It works now (I ultimately ended up moving the button element directly under the `<form>` element so there is only one `parentNode` like in the tutorial I was following.

Comment: Imray, that circular reference problem implies that you probably had an element added (by JavaScript) to one of its n-th child elements, and that might have been the source of your original error message. Anyway, glad you got it worked out. Cheers!